# Installing MSMQ in Linux or non-windows platform?

Tags: linux, jms, msmq

I want to know, can we install MSMQ on a Linux box, if so can you tell me what the procedure is and which so files I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the MSMQ specification was published so anyone can write an MSMQ stack of their own to run on any OS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. MSMQ is designed to run on Windows only. Your best option is to get a messaging product that works on Linux (like Websphere MQ) *and* provides some kind of bridge interop layer to communicate transparently with MSMQ on Windows, if you need something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**!

As per [Message Queuing (MSMQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) official site

**Run-Time Requirements**

```
MSMQ 1.0 can be deployed on computers running Microsoft® Windows NT® 4.0, Windows® 95, and Windows 98.

MSMQ 2.0 can be deployed on computers running Microsoft Windows 2000.

MSMQ 3.0 can be deployed on computers running Microsoft Windows XP Professional and members of the Windows Server 2003 family.

MSMQ is also available with independent client functionality on computers running Windows CE 3.0.
```

and

**Interoperability**

With the MSMQ-MQSeries Bridge, a connector application available in Microsoft Host Integration Server 2000, Message Queuing can be used to communicate with IBM MQSeries systems. For more information about the support for interoperability with other messaging systems using the MSMQ-MQSeries Bridge, see [Message Queuing Connector Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)